# How to isolate $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^{2}}$?

Tags: calculus, summation, riemann-sum

I have the following equation where $c$ may be some constant (derived from the Riemann sum of $\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{s^{2}}ds$):

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\left(n+i\left(x-1\right)\right)^{2}}=c$

Is it possible to isolate $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^{2}}$ on the LHS? I would be grateful for any help on this.

Comment: I find it rather confusing that your integral has the dummy variable in its upper bound as well. I'm not sure how to make sense of this. Also, what is the $x$ in your sum supposed to be?

Comment: It is incorrect to have the dummy variable in both the integrand and limits (for finite interpretation imagine the sum $\sum_{i=1}^i i$). I think what you mean is $\int_1^x \frac{1}{s^2}\,ds$.

Comment: Sorry, yes. Thank you.